# RunProcess and Ghostscript problem

Tags: external-calls, ubuntu, scripting

I have created a pdf from two plots with `GraphicsColumn` and now I need to get rid of the extra whitespace on the sides. Don't use `ImageCrop` for that because the image loses a lot of quality.

Usually I would use `pdfcrop` on the terminal to cut out the white space so thought of adding it to the Mathematica Notebook itself. The problem... even though the command works completely fine in my terminal, in the Mathematica Notebook it returns the following error

```
<|"ExitCode" -> 1, "StandardOutput" -> "PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 
by Heiko \Oberdiek.", "StandardError" -> "!!! Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 1!"|>
```

I ran it in two different ways. Both return the same error

```
RunProcess[{"pdfcrop", "file.pdf", "file.pdf"}]
RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "pdfcrop file.pdf file.pdf"]
```

Please help as to why Mathematica could be having a problem with Ghostscript.

Also if you could indicate what tags would be appropriate for this post I'd highly appreciate it.

Edit: I am on Ubuntu 17.10, have Ghostscript 9.21, GNU bash 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and Mathematica 11.

Comment: You should add your operating system as well.

Comment: Thanks! I have added that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX), which does call Ghostscript using `RunProcess`. I (used to) get a lot of support requests about MaTeX (before I included workarounds for most issues).

As I remember, some Linux users had trouble with it for the following reasons:

- The script that starts up Mathematica will change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux, so that Mathematica can find its own libraries.
- Ghostscript may use some of the same libraries that Mathematica ships with, but may not work correctly with them (so it just quits on startup).

*If* this is indeed the problem that you are running into, then the following should work:

```
$environment = Association@GetEnvironment[]; (* get all environment variables *)
KeyDropFrom[$environment, "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] (* remove LD_LIBRARY_PATH *)
RunProcess[{"gs", "--version"}, ProcessEnvironment -> $environment]
```

Let me know if it worked.

If this does not work, try running `gs --version` from Mathematica (as above, but without `ProcessEnviroment`) and post the output.

Comment: It worked! I honestly thought I wouldnt be able to get an answer! Thank you so much!